# Delphi XE7 Firemonkey: How to get locale dateformat set in device?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, date-formatting, delphi-xe7

I'm writing a mobile application for both iOS and Android and need to get the locale dateformat set in the device to display the date correct in tables and graphs.
How to get that format information?
I have searched both on google and within SO, without finding anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

/Lars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat;** and **FormatSettings.LongDateFormat;**